# How to parse and edit MS Visio file in java code

Tags: java, apache-poi, visio, aspose

I have checked multiple links and two options were shown for editing MS visio file in Java code.

1. Apache POI - HDGF and XDGF - Java API To Access Microsoft Visio Format Files
2. Aspose.diagram APIs

Has anyone done any coding in Java language using above option?
I am using eclipse IDE.

Also please suggest if there is third better way to edit MS visio file using java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about libraries, these are the two basically. Apache POI AFAIK can't create diagrams, **only read**, if I am not mistaking - but please verify, maybe something changed since I last looked at that ten years ago.

So this basically leaves you with a single choice. Or you can always spend a few　years and write it all yourself. Well, man does not simply <s>walk into mordor</s> create visio files with java.

Maybe you could consider using SVG instead, that can be generated and consumed by basically anything? Visio can also read and write SVG out of the box.

Comment: Can you please add any useful link for SVG parsing here. I have seen many options on Stack overflow showing use of JAXB library. I have used DOM parser earlier. But JAXB is difficult to understand.

Comment: You can use any xml parsing library, SVG is just XML. Apache Batik is one of the known ones that specializes in SVG. https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/